# AngularJS - Sliding Effect On ng-click

Tags: angularjs, css, angularjs-ng-click, ng-show

I have created a simple ng-click function that hides and shows a `DIV`.

However, rather and simply appearing and disappearing, does angular have the ability to give a sliding effect?

Here's a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/jbHidL3oOQvi4RBCkJIF?p=preview

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-wrap">
  <div class="grid-col one-third">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <a href="#" class="link" ng-click="showMe=!showMe">Show the slidy section</a>
  </div>


  <div class="grid-col two-thirds" ng-show="showMe">
    My hidden section that i want to slide out

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis irure dolor in repr</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a good read about ng-animate (it have to be injected into your app - something a lot of ppl forget) then you can take a look here
http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-switch/slider-css3-transition-animation

a well designed examples of what ng-animate can do

[Google CDN angularjs-animate.min.js](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular-animate.min.js)

Comment: ive had a look at ng-animate, ideally i would like to achieve this without having to import any more JS libraries.

Comment: It is doable, you can use `ng-class` and change class accordingly to what you want to do i.e. `hide-ya-wife` class for animate hiding or `show-me-the-money` for showing, then in CSS you just do a CSS animation of given element

Comment: makes sense, guess i need to research css annimations!

Comment: something from my resources:
http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/
http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/